# Composite INDEX vs individual INDEXES

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have the following query:

```
SELECT count(*) from main where platform_id='ACME' AND master_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Looking at my database, I have indexes on both `platform_id` and on `master_id`. Running this query took 8.1s.

I then added a composite INDEX:

```
ALTER TABLE main ADD INDEX (platform_id, master_id);
```

When I ran the query again, it only took 61.6ms, over 100x faster! My question is why does it make such a big difference in having both columns indexed together as opposed to two individual indexes in the above query?

Comment: When in doubts - check `EXPLAIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL can only use one index in a case like that.  It will choose either the platform_id index or the master_id index, depending on which one has the highest cardinality (number of distinct values in the index.)  You can see the cardinality of each index with `SHOW INDEXES`.  It is possible that the values MySQL has stored for cardinality aren't correct, in which case you can force it to recalculate them with `ANALYZE TABLE main`, but probably the results you're seeing are just because the distribution of unique values in those two indexes are such that it's not picking the most efficient one.  Using a composite index as you've done here is probably the best strategy.

Comment: When you make a query, it will always only use one index? So in other words if you make regular queries with multiple `WHERE` attributes you'd better have composite indexes?